# How to install LibreOffice using one-get?

Tags: windows, libreoffice, chocolatey, windows-packagemanagement

I thought I'd try to the one-get meta package manager that Microsoft has included in Windows 10. I found [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AptGetForWindowsOneGetAndChocolateyOnWindows10.aspx) useful article that goes over how to use 
it. One open source software that I had yet to install on my computer is LibreOffice, so after install the package provider `chocolately`, I then ran the following the command and it appears to install. However, I can't find any information about where it installed. I found that it created a folder in `C://chocolately`, but that appears to be mostly empty. Is there anything else I need to do to install LibreOffice?

```
get-packageprovider -name chocolatey
install-package libreoffice
```

Output after get-package provider:

```
Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
Chocolatey               2.8.5.130        SkipDependencies, ContinueOnFailure, ExcludeVersion, ForceX86, PackageSave...
```

There is no output after install-package libreoffice, however if I remove it and then reinstall it I get this output

```
The package(s) come from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'chocolatey'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y

Name                           Version          Source                         Summary
----                           -------          ------                         -------
libreoffice                    5.1.1            chocolatey                     LibreOffice is the free power-packed ...
```

Comment: Please post the output after typing both commands on the power shell.

Comment: Done, see post.

Comment: Just to make sure: there is no new start menu entry and there is no LibreOffice installed in C:/Program Files? You might try `choco install libreoffice` and add for verbose mode -v (--verbose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Chocolatey doesn't have an official OneGet provider released yet. For more information see http://us8.campaign-archive2.com/?u=86a6d80146a0da7f2223712e4&id=0165685e1f

Reposting the important parts:

> The current Chocolatey OneGet provider is not yet
>   complete. In fact it is a preview that was written in April 2014 and
>   is based on a two year old Chocolatey (even then it doesn't have all
>   the features).  I would consider it broken and incompatible with the
>   current choco CLI. We've heard reports of it working for some folks,
>   but for the vast majority of folks, you may run into issues with it.
>   So we recommend that you don't use it until we announce that it is
>   ready to use, which will be somewhere around the end of this year or
>   in Q1/Q2 2016. We are looking for folks to help out with this. If you
>   are interested, please reach out at
>   https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-oneget.

Comment: Ah thanks, the other posts I read implied that one-get support for Chocolately was good to go. Any update on this since we are entering the Q2 of 2016?

Comment: Updates are that once Kickstarter bits are complete and 0.9.10 is out, then there will be time for me to work on the provider if I am doing the work. Otherwise other folks are welcome to jump in sooner and help out.

Comment: Aha! So I found the real problem! When I tried to install chocolately manually, I go this error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170 That's why Chocolately wasn't working to begin with! I guess they need to work on error handling with one-get.

Comment: Yeah, if you drop to using the cmd.exe install instructions, it uses bypass as the security policy